# How to create the box application widgets as seen in Google Play?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-widget

For my Android application, I'm wondering how best to create the white box application widgets as seen in Google Play?  See the attached screenshot:

[image: Google Play Widgets]

You can either click on the widget itself, or you can click the 3-dot icon to bring up a menu.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try Gabriele Mariotti's excellent CardLibrary : https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically just create an image and set that image as the background (GridView in this example, the drawable would be the background of each cell)

you can also look at this library that does exactly what you want

https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib